# Python HTTPS client with basic authentication via proxy

Tags: python, proxy, https, basic-authentication

From Python, I would like to retrieve content from a web site via HTTPS with basic authentication. I need the content on disk. I am on an intranet, trusting the HTTPS server. Platform is Python 2.6.2 on Windows.

I have been playing around with urllib2, however did not succeed so far.

I have a solution running, calling wget via os.system():

```
wget_cmd = r'\path\to\wget.exe -q -e "https_proxy = http://fqdn.to.proxy:port" --no-check-certificate --http-user="username" --http-password="password" -O path\to\output https://fqdn.to.site/content'
```

I would like to get rid of the os.system(). Is that possible in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proxy and https wasn't working [for a long time](http://bugs.python.org/issue1424152) with urllib2. It will be fixed in the next released version of python 2.6 (v2.6.3).

In the meantime you can reimplement the correct support, that's what we did for mercurial: http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/rev/59acb9c7d90f

Answer (score 3):

Try this (notice that you'll have to fill in the realm of your server also):

```
import urllib2
authinfo = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
authinfo.add_password(realm='Fill In Realm Here',
                      uri='https://fqdn.to.site/content',
                      user='username',
                      passwd='password')
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"https" : "http://fqdn.to.proxy:port"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, authinfo)
fp = opener.open("https://fqdn.to.site/content")
open(r"path\to\output", "wb").write(fp.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this too:
   http://code.google.com/p/python-httpclient/

(It also supports the verification of the server certificate.)